# Convert interval datetime values to any-frequency time series

Tags: python, time-series, pandas, data-analysis

I have the following data structure:

```
2011-01-01 00:00, 2011-01-20 00:00, 200   # days-range
2011-01-20 00:00, 2011-03-08 00:00, 1288  # days-range
2011-04-11 00:00, 2012-01-08 00:00, 5987  # days-range

2012-02-01 00:00, 2012-02-01 01:00, 7     # hourly-range
2012-02-01 02:00, 2012-02-01 02:30, 3     # hourly-range
```

This is interval with **start date**, **end date** and **value** (some metric recorded between dates).

For further data analysis I need to generate time series with required frequency:
**monthly/daily/hourly/half-hourly** time series. For example, hourly data:

```
2011-01-01 00:00, 2 
2011-01-01 01:00, 6
2011-01-01 02:00, 5
...
```

**Is there any python lib which can help to implement this kind of data transformation?**

Comment: Yes, `pandas`. You have tagged it. But what are you doing with the values in the second column?

Comment: Have a look at http://pleac.sourceforge.net/pleac_python/datesandtimes.html then come back here with some code if you are stuck...

Comment: @eumiro Yes, pandas work great for further analysis, but before it,  I need to generate frequency time series from interval data. 
Example: I have 200 km tracked from 1st for Jan to 10th of Jan. I need to build values per day: 200/10 = 20 km per day. This is a simple case, of course.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
import pandas as pd

def stretch(start_date, end_date, value, freq):
    freq_dict = {'d': pd.datetools.day,
                 'h': pd.datetools.Hour(1)}
    dr = pd.DateRange(start_date, end_date, offset=freq_dict[freq])
    return pd.TimeSeries(value / dr.size, index=dr)


print stretch('2011-01-01 00:00', '2011-01-20 00:00', 200, 'd')
```

prints

```
2011-01-01    10
2011-01-02    10
2011-01-03    10
2011-01-04    10
2011-01-05    10
2011-01-06    10
2011-01-07    10
2011-01-08    10
2011-01-09    10
2011-01-10    10
2011-01-11    10
2011-01-12    10
2011-01-13    10
2011-01-14    10
2011-01-15    10
2011-01-16    10
2011-01-17    10
2011-01-18    10
2011-01-19    10
2011-01-20    10
```

Comment: Thanks, @eumiro, it is very helpful! Maybe pandas can solve another case: I have 200 km tracked from 1-10 of Jan, and 600km 11 Jan - 20 Feb, and I need monthly frequency, for Jan and Feb?

Comment: Create the individual daily TimeSeries, `combine` them and `groupby` them into month frequencies.

Comment: pandas's resampling capabilities will be vastly improved in the upcoming 0.8.0 release, keep an eye out.